# material.SetColor doesn't work PC/Android build

Tags: unity-game-engine

This script works as follows: when I raycast an object, it fades out.

Script works great in the **Unity Play Mode**.

But objects dont wanna fade out on **PC/Android build**. Just nothing happen, but raycast is detecting object (problem not in raycast)

I debugged Android/PC and script is going into *SetMaterialProperties* method

Standard material, default new project, default scene, simple capsule gameObject, nothing specific

Because of what could this be?

```
private IEnumerator FadeIn()
{
    Color objectColor = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color;

    while (objectColor.a < 1)
    {
        float fadeAmount = objectColor.a + (_fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        objectColor = new Color(objectColor.r, objectColor.g, objectColor.b, fadeAmount);

        SetMaterialProperties(objectColor);
        yield return null;
    }
}

private void SetMaterialProperties(Color color)
{
    foreach (var material in _materials)
    {
        material.SetColor("_Color", color);
        material.SetFloat("_Mode", 3);
        material.SetInt("_SrcBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.SrcAlpha);
        material.SetInt("_DstBlend", (int)UnityEngine.Rendering.BlendMode.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
        material.EnableKeyword("_ALPHABLEND_ON");
        material.renderQueue = 3000;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `_materials` XD?

Comment: @yasirkula my object contains of 2 parts of models, like wall and door. Wall and door have different materials

Comment: Can you put 2 dummy Cube objects to anywhere in your scene with the following materials: one is opaque and the other is transparent. Then try again?

Comment: @yasirkula I know what are you talking about. In some cases tranparent mode is solution to my problem (I tried it on simpe cube). If there is one cube - transparent mode is good solution, but in my case I have one object that consists of several objects (such a model was sent to me by a 3d artist). And it look terrible if I set transparent mode. So this solution won't work for me

Comment: You might need to enable keywords for _DstBlend and _SrcBlend for the platform targeted. Maybe... guessing... also for _Color and _Mode. Good luck!

Comment: As @Confused said, I'm suspecting that keywords are simply not included in build. Thus I've recommended putting 2 dummy Cubes with different keywords to force include them in the build.

Comment: @Confused thank you for answer, how can I "enable keywords for _DstBlend and _SrcBlend for the platform targeted" ?

Comment: @yasirkula Now in my scene 2 cubes. First cube is Standard Opaque. Second cube is Standard Transparent. Second cube is working fine in PC build, but first cube still no working. But i need Standard Opaque material...

Comment: @Rotmayer have a read of ALL of this, I know it's a pain, but Unity is very particularly odd, so it's important to read it all... https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-MultipleProgramVariants.html

Comment: after you've read all that, you'll have a much better chance of knowing how to get the name right, in terms of its _underScoresAndCapitalisation. I always have to try 3 or 4 different ways to get the name exactly right, so that it works: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Shader.EnableKeyword.html